# How to add mysql drivers to openshift tomcat

Tags: mysql, tomcat7, war, drivers, openshift-cartridge

I have deployed my war file on openshift tomcat. 
As suggested to deploy war file directly we need to remove the src and pom.xml before coping the war file in webapps folder. [pre compiled java applications (WAR and EAR files) onto your OpenShift](https://help.openshift.com/hc/en-us/articles/202399740)

Now since my application uses mysql driver - when tomcat starts on open shift it throws error of mysql driver classes not found.

How else can I add the mysql driver to openshift tomcat. Putting them in the web-inf/lib directory does not work since the datasources are configured on tomcat context.xml

Answer (score 0):

The data source configuration should not matter for the mysql driver. Before tomcat8 however there are scenarios where you have to deploy the mysql driver in the `tomcat/lib` (sad but it works). Upgrading to Tomcat8 will get you away from that scenario.